# Remove ^M at the end of each line in .txt file.

Tags: c

I have the following

```
^XA^M
^SZ2^JMA^M
^MCY^PMN^M
^PW822~JSN^M
^JZY^M
^LH0,0^LRN^M
^XZ^M
^XA^M
^FO350,95^M
^BY4^BCB,220,N,N,N,A^FD12345^FS
^FT605,700^M
^A0B,40,40^M
^FB600,1,0,R,0^M
^FD12345^FS
^FT282,1160^M
^A0B,28,39^FDBilka Tilst afdelingen^FS
^FT320,1160^M
^A0B,28,39^FDAgerÃ¸vej 7^FS
^FT358,1160^M
^A0B,28,39^FDPort 39^FS
^FT396,1160^M
^A0B,28,39^FDTilst^FS
^FT434,1160^M
^A0B,28,39^FDFLD_COUNTY_FLD^FS^M
^FT472,1160^M
^A0B,28,39^FD8381^FS
^FT510,1160^M
^A0B,28,39^FDFLD_COUNTRY_FLD^FS^M
^FT548,1160^M
^A0B,28,39^FDFLD_ORDERTEL_FLD^FS^M
^FO660,100^M
^GB0,720,2^FS^M
^FO750,100^M
^GB0,720,2^FS^M
^FO660,820^M
^GB92,0,2^FS^M
^FO660,100^M
^GB92,0,2^FS^M
^FT680,810^M
^A0B,18,23^FDDELIVERY INSTRUCTIONS:^FS^M
^FT700,810^M
^A0B,18,25^FDFLD_SPECIALINST1_FLD^FS^M
^FT720,810^M
^A0B,18,25^FDFLD_SPECIALINST2_FLD^FS^M
^FT200,1160^M
^A0B,80,90^FB1160,2,0,L,0^FDFLD_SERVICETEXT_FLD^FS^M
^FT780,1160^M
^A0B,18,20^FDSender's address: ^FS^M
```

I am trying to remove ^M at the end of each line, and have the following in C

```
GLOBAL BOOLEAN CARRIER_CONSIGNOR_SIM_ReplaceZPL(CARRIER_CONSIGNOR_SIM_ORDER_TYPE* Header)
{
  #define MAX_FILE_LEN 30

  char filename[MAX_FILE_LEN];
  snprintf(filename, MAX_FILE_LEN, "%s.zpl", Header->OrderNumber);

  FILE *file;
  FILE *write;
  char line  [256];
  char linec [256];

  file = fopen( filename, "r");
  write = fopen( filename, "r+");

  if( file != NULL )
  {
    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
    {
      strcpy(linec, line);
      fprintf (write , linec);
    }
    /* Close both files */
    fclose (write);
    fclose (file);
    printf("REPLACED LABEL in %s\n", filename);
    return ( TRUE );
  }

 return ( FALSE );
}/*CARRIER_CONSIGNOR_SIM_ReplaceZPL*/
```

I have tried doing the following to "rb+", "r+b and rb to the write = fopen but neither of this will remove ^M. What is the best way around this.

Comment: @Fredrik I tried dos2unix but tells me to install something. Cheers for the reply :)

Comment: Instead of putting together a dedicated C program, how about `perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' <file1> [file2] [...]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can just shorten the string by deleting ay `\r` or `\n` characters at the end, e.g. change:

```
  ...
  strcpy(linec, line);
  ...
```

to:

```
  int len;
  ...
  strcpy(linec, line);
  len = strlen(linec);                   // get length of string
  while (len > 0)                        // while string not empty
  {                                      // if last char is \r or \n
      if (linec[len - 1] == '\r' || linec[len - 1] == '\n')
      {
          linec[len - 1] = '\0';         // delete it
          len--;
      }
      else                               // otherwise we found the last "real" character
          break;
  }
  ...
```

Note that when you print the string you will need to add a line feed, e.g. use

```
fprintf(write, "%s\n", linec);
```

Comment: Darn - Somebody beat me to it.

Comment: `strcpy(linec, line);
      len = strlen(linec); // Get length of string
      if (len > 0 && linec[len - 1] == '\r') // If last char is ^M
      {
        linec[len - 1] = '\0';
      }
      fprintf (write , linec); ` I am trying to debug it now. I declared int len; at the top of my file. It still gives me the same output but I think it is not considering ^M it as the last character because it goes to the next line. When I run gdb I get the following: `^XA\r\n\`

Comment: As I mention in my answer below, I don't think this is right, since it assumes the line really ends with only the `\r`, while in reality there's a `\r\n` pair.

Comment: @unwind: thanks - I've updated the answer now so that is strips all `\r` or `\n` characters from the end of the string - hopefully this is a more useful and general solution

Comment: @user532339: answer now updated - try the new version if you've not yet got a working solution

Answer (score 1):

The ^M you're seeing is a way to represent carriage return (CR, 0x0d) character. It's followed by the line feed character which is what's ending the line for most Unix tools. This text file was probably written by a Windows program.

If you open the file in binary mode, you should be able to remove all the characters whose value is `'\r'`, which is how carriage-return is written.

Paul R's suggestion fails to realize the `'\n'` follows the `'\r'`, so I don't think it will work.

You could, however, do something like:

```
char *cr;

...

if((cr = strchr(line, '\r')) != NULL)
{
 *cr++ = '\n';
 if(*cr == '\n')
  *cr = '\0';
}
```

right after reading the line. This should work in text mode, too.

Comment: What about using strchr(buffer, '\n') with complete file as buffer content and replacing the ^M with " "´s? This would simply remove them and ignoring the rest. You think that might cause trouble?