# How to check YML grammar is correct (gitlab.yml)

Tags: syntax, yaml, markup, gitlab

[GitLab server can't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690321/bitnami-gitlab-5-2-0-gitlab-sidekiq-not-running-and-could-not-be-started). The reason is likely because gitlab.yml configuration file is not correct.

**What tool to use to check yml grammar is correct?**

I have tried Notepad++ and SublimeText, but they show small sign in different places:

Notepad doesn't like indent for 1 line.
[image: Notepad++]

SublimeText
[image]

Can really indents and spaces be problem in GitLab config parser?

Answer (score 1):

What I use, and this works with any editor, is a comparison between:

- `gitlab.yml`
- `gitlab.yml.example`

I developed a little [bash diff script](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/sbin/check_all_diff) which will look for differences in *keys* (not values, since you are supposed to put your own values there)

```
## LDAP setting
ldap:               (<--- it is a key)
  enabled: true
    ^^^     ^^^
    key      value
```

I just do a:

```
cd gitlab/config
check_all_diff .
```

That way, if there are any change in term of keys, key order, new keys or deleted keys, I can spot those when I upgrade gitlab.

To summarize, you need to copy in a [directory part of your `$PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path):

- [**`check_all_diff`**](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/sbin/check_all_diff)
- [**`check_diff`**](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/sbin/check_diff) (called by `check_all_diff`)

Don't forget to:

- `chmod 755 check_all_diff check_diff`
- don't introduce improper eol (end of line) character. If you did, a [`dos2unix` will take care of those](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64798/6309).

Comment: How to run check_all_diff ? It just gives me command not found (with or without sudo)

Comment: You need to copy the script (https://raw.github.com/VonC/compileEverything/master/sbin/check_all_diff) in a file name `check_all_diff`, `chmod 755 check_all_diff`, and make sure it is in a folder part of your `$PATH`.

Comment: Even after executing `chmod 755 check_all_diff` I can't make it run in any way: check_all_diff, ./check_all_diff, sudo check_all_diff, sudo ./check_all_diff -> bash: check_all_diff: command not found.

Comment: @PaulVerest but did you add the parent directory of that script in your `$PATH`? (http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/7490)

Comment: I am Windows user and expected that I can run from current folder.
I have just run PATH=$PATH:/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/config  
Now when running `check_all_diff`, I get /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: @PaulVerest Windows? In that case, make sure your Windows text editor doesn't save the file with bad eol (end of line) characters (like `\r\n`, instead of `\r`): that is the `^M` you see in the error message. Tools like Notepad++ or UltraEdit knows how to respect and not change those eol. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/q/10531472/6309, but also http://stackoverflow.com/a/73886/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3773847/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/64798/6309.

Comment: @PaulVerest Note: there are actually 2 scripts involved: `check_all_diff` and `check_diff`. I have edited my answer to make that clear.